# Show welcome message after user signup?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails, I'm trying to show a div with a welcome message and tips on what to do when the user signs up.

I know how to set flash messages after signup but this is more involved as the
div has a list and headers and so forth.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make a 'welcome' page?

If you have a static_pages controller, make a new page:

pages_controller.rb:

```
def first_time
  ...
end
```

And then in your `routes.rb` file:

```
get '/first_time',    :to => 'pages#first_time'
```

In your `users_controller`, do something like this:

```
def create
  ...
  if @user.save
    login @user
    redirect_to first_time_path
  else
    ...
  end  
end
```

Just remember to put a link in the `first_time` view to `/home` or wherever you want the user to end up after they see this page!

Comment: That would work, but I'd prefer to direct the user to their account settings page after signup, so they can start filling in their information because that's important for the application. So i wanted to show the welcome message at the top of the account settings page.

Comment: But if I can't figure out that, then the solution you provided will work great, so i appreciate your help.